# How to sort an array in descending order in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsarray, nssortdescriptor

I am trying to sort an array in descending order,I can sort array in ascending order,Here is my code to sort in ascending order,

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"year" ascending:NO];
NSArray * descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];

dictionaryWithSortedYears = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSString *tempDateKey = nil;

for (TreeXmlDetails *list in sortedArray)
{
    id obj = [dictionaryWithSortedYears objectForKey:list.year];

    if(!obj)
    {
        if(tempDateKey == nil)
        {
            arrayFromList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            tempDateKey = list.year;
        }
    }

    if([list.year isEqualToString:tempDateKey])
        [arrayFromList addObject:list];
    else
    {
        [dictionaryWithSortedYears setObject:arrayFromList forKey:tempDateKey];
        tempDateKey = nil;
        arrayFromList = nil;
        arrayFromList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        tempDateKey = list.year;
        [arrayFromList addObject:list];
    }
}

[dictionaryWithSortedYears setObject:arrayFromList forKey:tempDateKey];

NSArray *arr = [dictionaryWithSortedYears allKeys];

sortedKeys = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[arr sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)]];
```

But, I want to sort an array in descending array,Please help me.
Thanks in advnace.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
[yourArrayToBeSorted sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2){
    return [(NSDate *)obj2 compare:(NSDate *)obj1];} ];
```

Comment: You must have the 'yourArrayToBeSorted' of type NSMutableArray.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> An instance of NSSortDescriptor describes a basis for ordering objects
>   by specifying the property to use to compare the objects, the method
>   to use to compare the properties, **and whether the comparison should be
>   ascending or descending**. Instances of NSSortDescriptor are immutable.
>
> You construct an instance of NSSortDescriptor by specifying the key
>   path of the property to be compared, **the order of the sort (ascending
>   or descending)**, and (optionally) a selector to use to perform the
>   comparison.

The constructor:
**initWithKey:ascending:**

> Returns an NSSortDescriptor object initialized with a given property
>   key path and sort order, and with the default comparison selector.
>   - (id)initWithKey:(NSString *)keyPath ascending:(BOOL)ascending

The parameter that specifies the order:

> ascending YES if the receiver specifies sorting in ascending order,
>   otherwise NO.

And these apple docs guide you step by step on how to sort arrays:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/SortDescriptors/Articles/Creating.html